# Replication setup

Tags: replication, mysql-5.5, master-slave-replication

Currently, I have a production setup which consists of one Primary server and one Replica server, lets call them Primary1 and Replica1. All databases from Primary1 are replicating to Replica1.

Now, I have to introduce the second replica server, let's call it Replica2, which will be taking just one DB from Replica1.

So, the final look should be>

Primary1 -> Replica1 -> Replica2

On the Replica1, I configured log-slave-updates and configured log-bin. I was thinking of configuring binlog-do-db on the Replica1.

Replica2 configuration is pretty straight forward.

Now, the question is, are those 3 parameters (log-slave-updates, log-bin and binlog-do-db) on Replica1 enough to complete the setup I'm trying to achieve or do you have some other ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to answer my own question:

Yes, those 3 parameters were enough to achieve what I wanted.

So, the steps were to issue `stop slave` on the Replica1 and then stop the mysql service.

Then, configure those 3 options in my.cnf and start the service. After that, `start slave` on the Replica1 and everything is working like it should, binary logs are created with only one selected database.